# Select second element with diferent class of UL with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the next code:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
  <ul>
    <li class="mainclass class1-1"> </li>
    <li class="mainclass class1-1"></li>
    <li class="mainclass active"></li>
    <li class="mainclass class1-2"></li>
    <li class="mainclass class1-2"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to select the second type with class1-2 with the next lines but nothing happen:

```
#mainContainer li[class~="class1-2"]:nth-of-type(2){right:1.7em;}

#mainContainer li[class~="class1-2"]:nth-of-type(2){right:1.7em;}
#mainContainer ul li[class~="class1-2"]:nth-of-type(2){right:1.7em;}

#mainContainer li[class*="-2"]:nth-of-type(2){right:1.7em;}
#mainContainer ul li[class*="-2"]:nth-of-type(2){right:1.7em;}

.mainclass.class1-2:nth-of-type(2){right:1.7em;}
```

Exist some css selector especify for this case?

Comment: what do you want to select ?

Comment: sorry for that, I edited my post. @ashishsingh I want to select the second element with class "class1-2"

Comment: whats your use case to do so

Comment: the elements with class "class1-1 will be in the left" and elements with class "class1-2" will be in the right, but the second element in the right needs to go to right .3em more and the new third element in the right another .3em too.

Comment: I need to show the second magazine behind of first like this: https://ibb.co/eHiOMk

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can target the element on its own but if you only have the 2 elements with `.class1-2` then you can use the following:

```
.mainclass.class1-2 + .mainclass.class1-2 {
    right:1.7em;
}
```

Keep in mind this will affect additional elements that come directly after it with the same class.

Comment: yes, I thought in this too, but it will be more elements, and each one needs to go to right .3em more, like a stack of magazines. :(

Comment: for example, now, the first image hide the second, I need to show the second too, but a little to right, something like this https://ibb.co/eHiOMk

Comment: How many magazines are you going to have? You could always append another `+ .mainclass.class1-2` but it starts getting pretty ugly

Comment: 15 magazines, and the main idea is a slider